# XAML and Silverlight: Applying style to subclass fails

Tags: xaml, silverlight, inheritance, styles, subclass

I have created a subclass of TextBox

```
public class MyAwesomeTextBox : TextBox { ... }
```

and have set the color of all TextBoxes to be red

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <TextBox ... />
    <xyz:MyAwesomeTextBox ... />
</UserControl>
```

It works for all TextBoxes but not for MyAwesomeTextBoxes.

Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: `<Style TargetType="xyz:MyAwesomeTextBox">` since you're using it on the context of the UserControl

Answer (score 0):

I bet you set the `DefaultStyleKey` property to `typeof(MyAwesomeTextBox)` and now the framework will only apply a style with the specialized stylekey.
See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.defaultstylekey%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), I extracted the following part:

> If you do not set the DefaultStyleKey, the default style for the base class is used. For example, if a control called NewButton inherits from Button, to use a new default Style, set DefaultStyleKey to the type, NewButton. If you do not set DefaultStyleKey, the Style for Button is used.

So what can you do now? You can either remove the defaultStyleKey (but that means the TextBox style will be applied everywhere in your application and you cannot have you AwesomeControlTemplate applied to it by default, so I think this is not what you should do now) or you can add a derived style to your resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="BaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Style TargetType="MyAwesomeTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
</UserControl.Resources>
```